# updating contents of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a char * filed(name) in my struct in which I try to update it via p_update function it returns nothing(blank),so how can I update char * ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//------------------------------------------
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;
    }person;
void p_info(person *);
void p_update(person *);
//------------------------------------------
int main(void){
    person p1={"bob",22};
    p_info(&p1);
    p_update(&p1);
    p_info(&p1);
    return 0;
    }
//------------------------------------------
void p_info(person *p){
    printf("Name: %s\tAge: %i\n",p->name,p->age);
    }
void p_update(person *p){
    char name[10];
    scanf("%9s",name);
    p->name=name;
    }
```

Comment: `name` variable in `p_update` is an automatic/stack variable. It is only valid within the function. You need t o make a copy.  Something like `p-> name = strdup(name)`. Don't forget to free that memory when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your `p_update` finishes, your `char name[10];` disappears from memory. You need to either declare it as a global variable, or allocate a new chunk of memory:
`p->name = (char *) malloc(10); strcpy(p->name, name);` or simply `p->name = strdup(name);`

It would me much easier to alocate that buffer directly inside your struct:

```
typedef struct{
  char name[10];
  int age;
} person;
...
strcpy(p->name, name);
```

Comment: tnx,but I wonder when you define a string literal u cant change the contents of it cause of memory protection,so how does strcpy(p->name,name) does that?

Comment: `char name[10]` in the struct definition you mean? That is not a string literal. It is a character array and is definitely writable.

Comment: `const char * var = "abc";` is not writable, but `char var[10] = "abc";` is writable.

Answer (score 3):

> so how can I update char * ?

You're almost there.

Instead of `p->name=name;` use `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy( p.name, name );   // Note use this with modified `person` struct below.
```

The reason is that you can't use simple assignment for string type - you'll need `strcpy`, and `#include <string.h>` for that purpose.

Your `person` struct also needs work on as the `name` is an uninitialized pointer. It's better to use array instead.

```
typedef struct{
            char name[10];
            int age;
        } person;
```

With the same reason, you would need to declare and initialize your struct as follow:

```
// person p1={"bob",22};    // <-- WRONG
person p1 = {};
strcpy(p1.name, "bob");
p1.age = 22;
```

---

If you stick to `name` as char pointer, then you need an additional step to allocate the memory before use.

In `main()`:

```
// person p1={"bob",22};    // <-- WRONG
person p1 = {};
p1.name = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(p1.name, "bob");
p1.age = 22;
```

In `p_update()`:

```
// p->name=name;    // WRONG
p->name = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
strcpy( p->name, name );
```

Alternatively (as pelya pointed out), it's easier to use a single `strdup` here as it's equivalent to `malloc` + `strcpy`

```
p->name = strdup(name);
```

Comment: And then most probably he crashes :) because name is a pointer to `const char[4]`

Comment: `p->name` appears to be an invalid pointer. Should mention that memory needs to be allocated for it.

Comment: @dmi kaylum - agree I missed that.

Comment: by using p->name=name; I meant that p->name is pointer and name is also the address of first element of array so by that assignment the pointer p->name should point to array(name),whats wrong with  that?

Comment: That's a disaster because your local `name` would go out of scope when you return from that function - and now your pointer is pointing to non-existent location.

Comment: ok,I checked out the strcpy( p->name, name ); it gives bus error,I think its logical cause you try to copy to string literal which its in memory protection for over writting